# Why are uninitialized const members handled differently in C than in C++?

Tags: c++, c, constants

I am including a C header for a lib that I'm linking against.
The header has a struct `foo` of which I want to declare a new variable `bar`.
I get the compiler error:

```
 error: uninitialized const member in "struct foo"
```

It makes sense that these members need to be initialized since they can't be assigned values later on. But a C program that uses this library does the exact same thing and it works. Is there a difference in C and C++ standard?

This is just a sample. Actually I am referring to the struct `mtd_dev_info` from `libmtd.h` (mtd-utils). http://mtd-utils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.4.4/libmtd_8h_source.html

The struct in the header:

```
struct foo
{
    int major;
    int minor;
    int type;
    const char type_str[15];
    const char name[15];
};
```

My C++ application:

```
int main (int argc, const char ** argv)
{
  foo bar; 
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything specifically in any C standards that would tell about this; since const is kind of a second-class citizen in most C usage, I would say this is just some C legacy of "don't check too much we need to fit the copmiler in 640k RAM" of the good old times and no one of the C guys cared enough to specify it any better.

Comment: Are you sure your name should be a single character?

Comment: @dornhege Sorry, I copied that wrong. It's correct now. Actually I am referring to libmtd.h

Comment: Why do you think that would be valid C again?

Comment: In mtd-utils: [nandtest.c](https://gitorious.org/mtd-utils/mtd-utils/source/dea52ed97103050ec8e797aa0e084bfe090e0fd1:nanddump.c#L278) is declaring  `mtd_dev_info` from [libmtd.h](https://gitorious.org/mtd-utils/mtd-utils/source/dea52ed97103050ec8e797aa0e084bfe090e0fd1:include/libmtd.h#L70)

Comment: I dont think this is a good duplicate: a non-const `struct` with const members, in C, is quite a different situation to a standalone `const` variable.

Answer (score 4):

You **need** to fill these fields **because they're const**.

That means no assigning to them later -- while the other fields could get a value in a later step of your program (because they're mutable).

C just thinks it's okay to have const fields with undefined values that aren't modifiable in this compilation unit.

Comment: But why is it possible in C code to not have them initialized right away at declaration?

Comment: Because C is okay with `null` fields.

Comment: I don't think `const` fields are automatically zero-initialized.

Comment: Well, when I tried it was null. Do you mean that it doesn't wipe previous memory and could have random content ?

Comment: Yes, const adds nothing to initialisation value - it could be anything. `static` forces initialisation, but structs can't have static fields.

Comment: To sum it up - in C it is perfectly ok to have non-initialised consts. Moreover (just as well as in C++), `const` value could actually change - you're just asking compiler to issue an error if you're trying to modify it directly *within this translation unit*.

Comment: Well, yeah, and you could change it if you just got a pointer to its address, like private stuff and whatever.

Comment: Some variables are zero-initialized in C, specifically global and function static variables. Automatic (local) variables and malloc() storage have undefined value before the first assignment.

Comment: In C++ it would be undefined behaviour to write to a `const` member, so you risk getting your hard drive formatted if you change it.

Comment: @DonReba if it is `extern volatile const int` in one translation unit, but `volatile int` in another - is it undefined?

Comment: @keltar, the compiler would be free to assume, while compiling one unit that the value never changes and apply any optimization consistent with that assumption.
"Any attempt to cast away a `const` during an object's lifetime results in undefined behaviour."

Comment: Alright, updated with @keltar's comment.

Comment: @keltar “you're just asking compiler to issue an error if you're trying to modify it directly within this translation unit.” No, you are asking the compiler to optimize based on the promise that the value will not change. To see the difference, compile `const int x = 5;
void f(void);

int main(void) {
  f();
  return x;
}
` with optimization to assembly. When I do it on my computer, the function `main()` is compiled to `return 5;`. Do you think this would be a legal optimization if `x` was not `const` in the compilation unit containing `f()`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq not if it is extern or volatile, or both.

Comment: @keltar You said “const value could actually change - you're just asking compiler to issue an error if you're trying to modify it directly within this translation unit”. I have two compilers on my computer that think you are wrong, and that the value of `x` could NOT change. Each of these compilers transform the code in a way that is only correct if `x` does not change. Please retract or clarify your comment.

Comment: @PascalCuoq poor chose of words, sorry. While in your example `const` value is inlined, the same could be achieved with `static`. However, with combinations like `extern const` or `volatile const` it must not be inlined; so, while being `const`, this values still could be changed. I'm not sure it is safe to use on non-POD types, though.